# What is the proper way to dynamically add HTML to a Pug (Jade) template?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

Say we want to create a webpage using Pug and NodeJS that displays a list with items based on an external data source, e.g.:

```
doctype html
  ...
  body
    p Welcome to #{siteName}
    each item in variableWithExternalData
        ul
          li= item
```

Current approach:

1. User visits page
2. Server sends request to external API
3. Server processes external data and stores this in `data`
4. Render the page using `res.render('index', {siteName: 'MyName', variableWithExternalData: data});`

While this works fine, it is not particularly a swift client-side experience as the server first has to process the external data before it renders the page. What would be much more preferred is something like the following:

1. User visits page
2. Server renders the page
3. Server sends request to external API
4. Server processes external data
5. Client side retrieves data from server and dynamically adds it to the page

This would be beneficial as the page can render before retrieving and processing the external data, especially since the `ul` is not directly visible when the page loads. I am aware that it is possible to do something like the above by making a request from the client side using Ajax and subsequently add the items to the list using JavaScript. However, I wonder if there is a more serverside based approach allowed by Pug, e.g. some form of callback in the `pug.render()`?

Comment: I've added second example for you using external API and Pug template library, enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send part of the page (HTML markup), using chunked response, then after more data is processed on the back-end, send another chunk of the page. However this approach has some limitations, you cannot insert content in-between already sent data.

As for Pug, it is templating library and has nothing to do with sending data back to client. You can use Pug to create HTML for full page, or just a part of it. Then send output from Pug according to your wishes.

## Example #1

Below I've written simple NodeJS demo showcasing sending HTML in chunks. New chunk will be sent each second. After 10 chunks, closing tags will be sent. Each chunk should be rendered in the browser as soon as it arrives.

```js
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000
const hostname = 'localhost'
const server = http.createServer(main)

function main (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')
    res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')

    let chunksLeft = 10

    res.write('<DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Chunked response demo</title></head><body>')
    res.write(`<h1>Hello chunks!</h1><p>I will be sending ${chunksLeft} entries.</p><ol>`)

    function sendChunk () {
        chunksLeft -= 1
        res.write(`<li>Entry</li>`)
        if (chunksLeft > 0) {
            setTimeout(sendChunk, 1000)
        } else {
            res.end('</ol></html>')
        }
    }

    sendChunk()
}

function message () {
    console.log(`Listening on ${hostname}:${port}...`)
}

server.listen(port, hostname, message)
```

## Example #2

Below is code showcasing using axios and pug libraries for fetching and rendering data from external API, using concepts from previous example.

```js
const http = require('http')
const axios = require('axios')
const pug = require('pug')
const port = 3000
const hostname = 'localhost'
const server = http.createServer(main)

const template =
`doctype html
html
    head
        title Chunked response with pug and axios
    body
        h1 Hello chunks!
        p Below is example data downloaded from <a href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos">jsonplaceholder</a> and transformed to HTML.`

const list =
`ol
    each t in todos
        li= t.title`

function main (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')
    res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')

    res.write(pug.render(template))

    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(reply => {
        res.end(pug.render(list, { todos: reply.data }))
    }).catch(() => {
        res.end(pug.render('p Error: could not download todos!'))
    })
}

function message () {
    console.log(`Listening on ${hostname}:${port}...`)
}

server.listen(port, hostname, message)
```

More information:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding
- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding
- https://strongloop.com/strongblog/streaming-chunked-html-node-js-data/

Comment: Thank you. While this is not directly applicable in the example I illustrated in my question, it has been very insightful. To add on my example, making a request from the client side using Ajax and subsequently add the items to the list using JavaScript is probably the best approach, right?

Comment: Using AJAX on client side is usually chosen because it gives more flexibility, it allows to "inject" data anywhere you want. It all depends on your situation (business requirements, codebase, etc.). If you really want to render server-side, it is certainly possible. Switch setTimeout with request to external API, then process response from API (compile with pug for example), then pass the result to `res.write()` to send it to the client side, then finish with `res.end()`. As a side note, it is also possible to stream rendering infinite gif images from back-end, example: https://lwan.ws/.

Comment: Awesome! Love the approach. Definitely got some play time to spend now ;-)